# Macbook Pro is NOT showing up Bootable USB Drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac, usb, uefi

**System**: Macbook Pro 2019, Intel, T2 Chip, 16 GB RAM, No USB port (Using VIVA USB hub), Ventura 13.6.5

**Issue**: The ***bootable USB drive (EFI) is not showing up*** when restarting with 'Option' key

I had problem with Hash Volume Mismatch. Upgrade did not solve the issue, then I completely reinstalled Ventura.

Now, I wanted to **dual boot** MacOS with Debian. I disabled T2 Chip, and partitioned the Internal Hard drive.

But, when I tried with a TimeShift USB Drive, it is showing up the EFI (USB Drive)

What is the solution? I prefer dual booting it with MacOS and Debian.